Neovim: override Treesitter spelling settings
I'm coding in Neovim in a programming language that gets highlighting from Treesitter. This means the regions that are spellchecked are also controlled by Treesitter. I want to have more than just comments spellchecked, so I've been going into the relevant highlights.scm files and adding @spell to nodes I want checked. This is obviously not a great idea since these files get updated when Treesitter does. Is there a good way to  override these spelling settings?

Going to try this later as I have the same problem. If there is no option or override then you could fork the tree sitter repo and you then pull from that repo. Would mean setting up alerts on keeping your fork in sync with the original but at least you won't have to rewrite your changes each time.
